# tar incremental copy error

Tags: bash, tar

I've checked other related post (with similar questions about how to make incremental tar copy)and their answers does not apply on my case.

The problem:
I've a big (around 700/800Gb) directory with many subdirectories with the content in /storage.
The copy is stored inside a directory in /storage/backup
If we limit the copy to a /storage/subdirectory (8Gb length) first complete tar works, and an incremental copy after seems to be correct (only some Kb len).
If we do the tar in the /storage (excluding /storage/backup) the complete tar finish but throws an error (-2) after finishing, but it seems to uncompress correctly if we test it, we have to stop the incremental backup after it because it begins to grow and seems to be growing to the same size the comlpete backup.
Same original script was running on other server with more content and incremental sizes should be only 1/2Gb not growing and growing...

Script simplified code. the day it should be complete is hardcoded day 12 example, if we launch it on 12th it makes the complete copy, if 2 days after we launch the incremental copy, it seem to grow to complete size...

```
    #!/bin/bash
    name_backup="mybck"
    data_dir="/storage"
    dir_bkp="/storage/backup/MonthCopy"
    data_dirs_exclude="/storage/backup"
    make_complete_day="${1:-12}"
    mydate="$(date "+%Y%m%d")"
    #Filenames
    fname_bkp="${dir_bkp}/${name_backup}-${mydate}"
    fname_inc="${dir_bkp}/mybck.incremental"
    fname_inc_save="${dir_bkp}/mybck.incremental.save"
    fname_log="${fname_bkp}.log"
    #Compression parameters
    export XZ_OPT="-3 -T0 -Csha256"
    today="$(date "+%d")"
    if [ "${make_complete_day}" -eq "${today}" ]
      then
        echo Its _complete copy
        fname_bkp="${fname_bkp}-complete.tar.xz"
        time nice -n 19 ionice -c2 -n7 tar -cpf "${fname_bkp}" --use-compress- 
   program=xz --exclude="${data_dirs_exclude}" --listed-incremental 
    "${dir_bkp}/snapshot.file" "${data_dir}" && {
          echo "Copy OK($?).";
        } || {
          err=$?
          echo "Error in copy($err)."
        }  
      else
       echo Incremental copy
       fname_bkp="${fname_bkp}-incremental.tar.xz"
       time nice -n 19 ionice -c2 -n7 tar -cpf "${fname_bkp}" --use-compress- 
  program=xz --exclude="${data_dirs_exclude}" --listed-incremental 
    "${dir_bkp}/snapshot.file" "${data_dir}" && {
         echo "Copia OK($?).";
        } || {
          err=$?
          echo "Error in copy($err)."
        }  
    fi
```

Tar version is: tar (GNU tar) 1.26

Is there any error in my tar complete and incremental copy after that?
If not, any suggestion about what to try?
Regards.

Comment: Do you get a return value of 2 (`Fatal error`)?  I can't see how you can get -2, since the exit code is unsigned.   From the GNU doc:  *If tar has invoked a subprocess and that subprocess exited with a nonzero exit code, tar exits with that code as well. This can happen, for example, if tar was given some compression option... and the external compressor program failed.*  Did you get any messages to stderr?

Comment: ok, error code is 2.There is no more messages to console, only some errors on files not present, it tooks 3 days to comlpete meanwhile some files are added or removed from the /storage directory. I was thinking for example if --exclude was not working correctly, as all subdirectories are in number format to use some mask in the tar to include all /storage/beginwithnumber as an alternative not using --exclude. How can check it?
If xz is failing it's a problem because xz with these parameters compress much more than using the standard J option in tar, much more efficient and compress ratio.

Comment: Can you experiment with a small number of files with and without files not present?  Error 2 in C is ENOENT, No such file or directory, so it *might* just be indicating that.  Experimenting with the same small set would find if that is true or not.

Comment: cdarke, I've executed the script in a 1.5Gb subdirectory with around 3000 files, it took 3 minutes, before running it, we copy a file as 1, 2.. to 15, and each 10/20 seconds I manually deleted one of the copied files. I get no error. After we change script day and it did an incremental (only some Kb copy) No error.